# Why downloaded apk files are not displaying in Vuzix SmartGlass's download folder?

Tags: android, vuzix, vuzixm100

Now I developed the android application for Vuzix SmartGlass. And I uploaded the apk files in google drive and shared the link to my customer to download the apk.

After my customer downloaded the apk files, those downloaded files are not displaying in the download folder apps of smart glass. When I connect the device with laptop and search in the folder, I can be able to see the downloaded files in download folder.

Have anyone of you encountered this kind of issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use our Smart Glasses System File Manager to load APKs directly to the M300/M100. You can download and install System File Manager from (http://files.vuzix.com/Content/Upload/M100%20System%20File%20Manager%204.0.0.zip)
 or you can install via adb simply issue the command ‘adb install .apk’ from within the directory that contains the apk.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience the only working way of installing apps on the device is the M100 System File Manager.

Your customers can get it from here even without registration:
https://www.vuzix.com/support/Downloads_Drivers